# How do I get Windows XP Embedded to serve DHCP over wireless?

Tags: windows, dhcp, wifi, windows-xp

I have a Windows XP Embedded machine with a wireless connection. I'd like it to act as a wireless hotspot so that clients can connect to it with their devices and not have to worry about setting their IP addresses to match.

What free software is there available to do this or can it be done from Windows itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed once to use a dhcp service in Windows XP I guess you can use this:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/dhcp-dns-server/files/

Disclaimer: I don;t know the limitations in XP Embedded, so, let me know if this doesn't fit your needs to remove it from here.

HTH

Comment: Thanks for the link. I found another option which is just a DHCP server here: http://ruttkamp.gmxhome.de/dhcpsrv/dhcpini.htm

Comment: That's a dual service. It can be used as DHCP, DNS or both.
Cheers!